# Word leverage. Synonyms, antonyms and asociation

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

What are at least two synonyms, two antonyms for a verb: to leverage? I'm hopeless, thanks for the answer. By the way, do you have any association with this word? I do homework and I do not know how to answer these questions.

Comment: This is what a thesaurus is for.

Comment: Yeah, see what you can pry out of a thesaurus.  Maybe you can jimmy some ideas loose.

Answer (score 0):

A lever is a device that can be used to lift up much heavier objects. In finance this word is associated with taking a loan so that you can buy a lot more stuff than you could have done with your original money. In this sense, the leverage allows you to buy more expensive objects. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever, since I think that seeing a lever explains the idea of the word quite nicely.

Now this word describes a fairly niche concept as we can see so most synonyms would inevitably lose some part of the meaning that this word carries, especially in a financial context. However possible synonyms are *to fund* and *to lift*. An antonym would be a word that describes an action where a lot of effort accomplishes very little, so *to be stuck*  and *to stagnate*  are probably reasonable guesses.